# Route Model Binding target to abstract class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Assume the following model arquitecture:

```
namespace MyApp\Models;

abstract class Person{

    abstract function getName();
}
```

Then, I implement it in Employ:

```
namespace MyApp\Models;

class Employ extends Person{

    public function getName(){
        return "Employ";
    }
}
```

The same for User:

```
namespace MyApp\Models;

class Employ extends User{

    public function getName(){
        return "User";
    }
}
```

Here comes the funny.. I am using my own resolution logic int routes binding the models above.

```
Route::bind('person', function($value)
{
    // this method returns an instace of Employ OR User
    $person = load_person_from_db($value);
    return $person;
});

Route::get('test/{person}', function(MyApp\Models\Person $person){
    return $person->getName();
});
```

The problem? when I access the url...

```
 http://example.com/test/1
```

...the following exception triggered:

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 785: 
Target [MyApp\Models\Person] is not instantiable.
```

Yeah!, I know that `Person` is not instantiable, but why laravel is not returning the instance loaded by me at this point? `$person = load_person_from_db($value);`.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you remove the type hint (`MyApp\Models\Person`) from the route callback?

Comment: LOL... yeah, that woks!

Comment: Laravel 5 tries to do Dependency Injection where possible, that's why you need to omit it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel tries to resolve dependencies injected into a route closure. The solution is to simply remove the type hinting:

```
Route::get('test/{person}', function(MyApp\Models\Person $person){
    return $person->getName();
});
```

---

Interestingly, Laravel does check if the parameter has already been resolved by a model binding. However the problem is, it does that by comparing the class:

`Illuminate\Routing\RouteDependencyResolverTrait`

```
protected function alreadyInParameters($class, array $parameters)
{
    return ! is_null(array_first($parameters, function($key, $value) use ($class)
    {
        return is_object($value) && get_class($value) === $class;
    }));
}
```

So because your type hint says `Person` but your model binding returns something else, Laravel tries to resolve the dependency through the IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use app()->bind(%AbstractClass%, %Implementation%) (in __construct method of controller for example) and router will resolve your model